# Moq - Create inline fake for simple factory created DTO interface

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq

I have a simple abstract factory that returns a simple type. Basically, it just populates the type with data and returns it, similar to a DTO.

```
public interface IPagingInstructionFactory
{
    IPagingInstruction Create(int skip, int take, IProvider provider);
}

public interface IPagingInstruction
{
    int Skip { get; }
    int Take { get; }
    IProvider Provider { get; }
}
```

I now want to create a mock factory that basically does the same thing as the real one - which passes the parameters from the Create() method and returns them from the IPagingInstruction instance's properties.

Here is an example that works:

```
var pagingInstructionFactory = new Mock<IPagingInstructionFactory>();
pagingInstructionFactory
    .Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<IProvider>()))
    .Returns((int skip, int take, IProvider provider) => 
        new FakePagingInstruction(skip, take, provider));


public class FakePagingInstruction
    : IPagingInstruction
{
    public FakePagingInstruction(
        int skip,
        int take,
        IProvider provider
        )
    {
        if (provider == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("provider");

        this.skip = skip;
        this.take = take;
        this.provider = provider;
    }
    private readonly int skip;
    private readonly int take;
    private readonly IProvider provider;

    public int Skip
    {
        get { return this.skip; }
    }

    public int Take
    {
        get { return this.take; }
    }

    public IProvider Provider
    {
        get { return this.provider; }
    }
}
```

It seems to me that Moq should be able to create a fake object that can return all 3 properties instead of using a hand-coded fake. However, I can't seem to figure out how to make it return the values that are passed as parameters into the fake factory.

Can this be done, or do I need to use a hand-coded fake every time I need to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
var pagingInstructionFactory = new Mock<IPagingInstructionFactory>();
this.pagingInstructionFactory
    .Setup(x => x.Create(It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<int>(), It.IsAny<IProvider>()))
    .Returns((int skip, int take, IProvider provider) => 
    {
        var instruction = new Mock<IPagingInstruction>();
        instruction.Setup(i => i.Skip).Returns(skip);
        instruction.Setup(i => i.Take).Returns(take);
        instruction.Setup(i => i.Provider).Returns(provider);

        return instruction.Object;
    });
```

This will setup `Create` to return a new instruction every time it's called. If you want to return the same instance *or* if you want to perform some assertions on the instruction later on, you'll have to move the declaration out of the delegate.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis, but other than that it works.

Comment: Lifesaver! :) Thanks!